# Dispose DBContext when request completes when using MEF for dependency injection

Tags: asp.net-web-api, mef

I am currently working on a `Web API` project that uses `MEF` for dependency injection.

In other projects I have used `Unity` and its `PerRequestLifetimeManager` to dispose the `DBContext` when the request completes.

However, I could not find a way to perform the same task with `MEF`.

So my question is - how can I dispose the `DBContext` when the request completes when using `MEF` for dependency injection?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Yes, turned out that MEF was a poor choice for a web application. I evaluated MEF 2.0 and Autofaq integration with MEF. For the former this might help: https://blog.softwarepotential.com/porting-to-net-standard-2-0-part-2-porting-mef-1-0-to-mef-2-0-on-net-core/ . Sorry I don't remember more than that.